# MySQL query from subquery not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return a number based on the count of results from a table and to avoid having to count the results twice in the IF statement I am using a subquery. However I get a syntax error when trying to run the query, the subquery I have tested by itself runs fine.

Any ideas what is wrong with the query? The syntax looks correct to me

```
SELECT IF(daily_count>8000,0,IF(daily_count>6000,1,2))
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) as daily_count
    FROM orders201003
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),"%d-%m-%y") =
    DATE_FORMAT(reqDate,"%d-%m-%y")
) q
```

Error message I get is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax. 
>   Check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'SELECT 
>   count(*) as daily_count
>           FROM    orders201003

Comment: Could you please post the syntax error you get?

Comment: @Quassnoi, updated with the error message - not sure how helpful it is  though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN daily_count > 8000 THEN 0 WHEN daily_count > 6000 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
FROM    (
        SELECT  count(*) as daily_count
        FROM    orders201003
        WHERE   DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),"%d-%m-%y") =
                DATE_FORMAT(reqDate,"%d-%m-%y")
        ) AS q
```

Also note that the nested queries are only supported starting from `MySQL 4.1`.

Comment: @Quassnoi Should it make a difference when using `CASE` instead of `IF`?

Comment: @James: No, this is just more legible. Which `MySQL` version do you use? Try adding `AS` before the query alias, this may be required for the older versions.

Comment: Version is 4.0.21, just found out that it doesn't support subqueries :(

Comment: @James: `MySQL 4.0` does not support nested queries. You should use `COUNT(*)` instead.